# Android quotes within an sql query string

Tags: android, sqlite

I want to perform a query like the following:

```
uvalue = EditText( some user value );
p_query = "select * from mytable where name_field = '" +  uvalue + "'" ;
mDb.rawQuery( p_query, null );
```

if the user enters a single quote in their input it crashes.  If you change it to:

```
p_query = "select * from mytable where name_field = \"" +  uvalue + "\"" ;
```

it crashes if the user enters a double quote in their input.
and of course they could always enter both single and double quotes.

Comment: miannelle, check out these related questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29699/how-do-i-deal-with-quotes-in-sql http://stackoverflow.com/questions/387198/escape-double-quotes-in-sql-2005-2008

Comment: miannelle: You should look at marking some of your questions as "answered"

Answer (score 131):

You should make use of the [`rawQuery`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#rawQuery(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[])) method's `selectionArgs` parameter:

```
p_query = "select * from mytable where name_field = ?";
mDb.rawQuery(p_query, new String[] { uvalue });
```

This not only solves your quotes problem but also mitigates [`SQL Injection`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sql_injection).

Comment: I wish I could upmod this more than once!

Comment: It is also much faster because Sqlite doesn't have to parse every sql statement.

Comment: Indeed, you should use query arguments. However, you can also use the DatabaseUtils to escape strings, if needed. For instance, DatabaseUtils.sqlEscapeString(). It's not the best way, but it's available. Could be useful if you're trying to pass a raw SQL statement over to something external.

Comment: @lilbyrdie: thanks! As one can't bind vectors of strings for use with the IN operator, sqlEscapeSting() was just what I needed!

Comment: This doesn't work as well as you'd think. If you use a string like this it breaks: "sample " string ' that breaks stuff"

Comment: Using 'selectionArgs' parameter doesn't work when the question mark goes within a 'LIKE' string (for example: SELECT * FROM Table WHERE column LIKE '%?%'). In this case, you have to use string concatenation and DatabaseUtils.sqlEscapeString is a good practice in order to avoid SQL injection.

Answer (score 14):

DatabaseUtils.sqlEscapeString worked properly for me. The string is enclosed by single quotes and the single quotes inside the string become double quotes. 
Tried using selectionArgs in the getContentResolver().query() but it didn't work at all.

Comment: The `DatabaseUtils.sqlEscapeString` replaces one or two special characters where the need is to replace all special characters, isn't there any way to replace specified or all special characters?

Answer (score 5):

You should change

```
p_query = "select * from mytable where name_field = '" +  uvalue + "'" ;
```

like

```
p_query = "select * from mytable where name_field = '" + android.database.DatabaseUtils.sqlEscapeString(uvalue)+ "'" ;
```

Comment: but your need remove quotes because they are added by default

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried replacing a single quote with 2 single quotes? That works for inputting data to a database.

Comment: I would prefer to use the top answer, but in my case it was not possible do to application design.  This works too

Answer (score 3):

I prefer to escape Single quotes and Double quotes in each insert statement with Sqlite like this:

```
 String sqlite_stament = sqlite_stament.replace("'", "''").replace("\"", "\"\"");
```

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem but now it is solved by just writing the code like 
in your case you want to insert value uvalue .Then write as

```
uvalue= EditText( some user value );
uvalue = uvalue.replaceAll("'", "''");
p_query = "select * from mytable where name_field = '" +  uvalue + "'" ;
mDb.rawQuery( p_query, null );
```

cool..!!

Comment: that's stupid, you're replacing ' with '' which will still causes issues.

Comment: @stealthcopter That's not stupid, the standard SQL way of escaping a single quote in a string literal is to double it so `''''` is an SQL string literal which contains one single quote. Manually escaping strings for SQL may not be the best idea but the result is correct in this case.