# Escape special characters in sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite

I am trying to update a SQLite table in my Android application. Predicate for this update is built around a column which stores different resource URLs.

These URLs might contain special characters such as /~?=; (and even &).

My query looks like:

```
update TableName where columnVal = '/some/fake/~/id?u=0&amp;rl=url';
```

The update query doesnt work; it does not identify the column satifying the condition.

How can I escape these characters?

Please advise.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be using the method `update` instead of generating the SQL yourself. The built-in methods will do all the needed escaping for you.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html

Comment: I don't mean to be a douchebag, but this is not really an answer to the OP's question, though, is it? :)

Answer (score 2):

Answered here: [Android quotes within an sql query string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1296180/android-quotes-within-an-sql-query-string)

Comment: this only escapes quotes and doublequotes, no? doesn't handle any other special characters