# Include slashes in sqlite insert statements

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I am trying to execute `INSERT` sqlite statements into my database using a method as follows:

```
public void insertBluetoothPath(String path, String build) {

    String[] ColumnName = new String[1];
    ColumnName[0] = "path";

    SQLiteDatabase myDB = null;
    myDB = this.openOrCreateDatabase(DB_PATH, MODE_PRIVATE, null);

    myDB.execSQL("INSERT INTO phones VALUES(" + build + ", " + path + ");");
    myDB.close();

}
```

and I'm calling the method using 
`insertBluetoothPath(finalPath, phoneBuild);`

with variables
`String phoneBuild = Build.MODEL;` and `String finalPath = "/mnt/sdcard"`

However I'm getting a syntax error exception

```
sqlite returned: error code = 1, msg = near "/": syntax error

Failure 1 (near "/": syntax error) on 0x2b3ca8 when preparing 'INSERT INTO phones VALUES(sdk, /mnt/sdcard);'.
```

How can I insert slashes into the database? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try to use prepared statements - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/433392/how-do-i-use-prepared-statements-in-sqlite-in-android

Comment: You should use escape characters for that.Check this post.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4132996/escape-special-characters-in-sqlite

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, Carefully go over Eugene's Comment.

The problem is not the slashes...The Problem is your insert statement.
An INSERT statement should look like this "INSERT INTO phones VALUES('sdk','/mnt/sdcard')"
Notice the Lack of single quotes in your statment?

This is what you want

```
myDB.execSQL("INSERT INTO phones VALUES('" + build + "', '" + path + "');");
```

But if you ask me, don't use this method, use Prepared Statements, since the above method will be prone to SQL injection, if you are not careful.

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap the path in single quotes like this.

```
myDB.execSQL("INSERT INTO phones VALUES(" + build + ", " + "'" + path + "'" + ");");
```

I think that should help.