# how to use string with apostorphy sign in android database

Tags: android, database

I am working on one application in which I have to save the data in database and retrieve  data..up to that its okay but when i retrieve data using particular name which already stores in database and if that name is like "**crown`s**" then it gives me force close..

so guys help me how can i stores name which contained special character and retrieve using the same...

i m using function of database to retrieve that is :

```
{
String name_search=edittext.getText().toString();
Cursor c=DB.rawQuery("select NAME from Category where NAME='"+name_search+"'",null);

}
```

thanks in advance....
please help me as eaerly as possible

Comment: Check out this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1296180/android-quotes-within-an-sql-query-string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use of the `selectionArgs` parameter to solve your issue

```
String name_search=edittext.getText().toString();
String query = "select NAME from Category where NAME= ?";
Cursor c=DB.rawQuery(query, new String[] { name_search});
```

Comment: thanks..i will try it..but can i store special character same like normal character in database or i have to do something to store that special character..

Comment: thank you..it works fine for me..please can u tell me how can i use the same thing for update the database row..