# How to escape special characters in sqlite in android?

Tags: android, sqlite

I ma trying to insert some data into the database. The data contains single quotes. I tried to escape them with back slash like "Scr\'anton" while inserting the data:

```
INSERT INTO employee VALUES(4,'Jim','Halpert','Assistant Regional Manager','Manage',2,'Scr\'anton','570-222-2121','570-999-1212','jim@dundermifflin.com','halpert.jpg')
```

I tired to use DatabaseUtils.sqlEscapeString() with no effect at all. What is the best way to escape characters?

Comment: if you'll use http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#insert(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues%29 than you will not worry about "escaping"

Comment: I think you need to use Escape clause in SqlLite. Something like this.LIKE ('Scr\'anton' ESCAPE '\' )

Comment: Answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1296180/android-quotes-within-an-sql-query-string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use double single quotes 'Scr''anton'

Comment: Thank you +++. Solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at `StringEscapeUtils` (details [here](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html)), found in the [Lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang/) component of Apache Commons. You can easily download this and add it to your project.

Comment: Seems a bit heavy just for doing a string replace of single quotes with double single quotes. You can do that with one line of code vs importing an entire lib.

Comment: @ChristopherPerry, what is the single line you're talking about? Would you mind provide it in a comment? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the method update
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html