# App crashes when I type ' in SearchView

Tags: android, sqlite

I am developing an app in which suggestive list is displayed as I start typing in `SearchView`. Everything is going well but as I type in `SearchView` the App just crashes.

```
 public Cursor searchByBrandText(String inputTextBrand) throws SQLException {
            db = this.getReadableDatabase();
            String where = inputTextBrand;
            String extra = "'%" + where + "%'";
            String query = "SELECT Brand_Name" + " from " + "Sample" + " where "
                    + "Brand_Name" + " LIKE " + extra;

            Cursor mCursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);

            if (mCursor.getCount() <= 0) {
                mCursor.close();
                return null;
            } else {
                return mCursor;
            }
        }
```

Comment: I think you've forgotten to add your error log...

Comment: can u plz tell me how to use bound parameters????

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android quotes within an sql query string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1296180/android-quotes-within-an-sql-query-string)

Comment: i am trying to replace null from rawQuery by new string[]{ } but crashing is not resolved on typing '

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**'** is the SQL string delimiter.
You have to **double** it, if you need to insert a value containing that character.
Like so:

```
String where = inputTextBrand.replace("'", "''");
```

Or, better, use **bound parameters** (in this case there's no need to double the **'**).
Like so:

```
String query = "SELECT Brand_Name FROM Sample WHERE Brand_Name LIKE ?";
Cursor mCursor = db.rawQuery(query, new String[]{"%" + inputTextBrand + "%"});
```

Answer (score 0):

The single quotation mark is messing up your sql query, this is reasonably serious because as it is somebody could use your text box to carry out an SQL Injection Attack on your database.

The method of dealing with this has been answered here: [Android Quotes within an SQL query string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1296180/android-quotes-within-an-sql-query-string)